# Simple HTML DOM parser (insert text/element after other element)

Tags: php, insert, addition

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser for my project..

WHat I'm stuck on currently is how I can target/find all TEXT nodes... and either add an element or even TEXT at the END of the TEXT..

Here is what Im trying so far.. but figured there might be a better (working ) way?  :)

```
$var = "INSERT TRANSLATION HERE >>";
foreach($html->find('text') as $tn){
    //$tn->outertext = $tn->makeup() . $tn->innertext . $var';
    $tn->innertext = $tn->innertext . $var;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is good, you just forgot to call `save`:

```
$string = "<div id='container'><div>im a text node</div><div>im another</div></div>";
$html = str_get_html($string);
foreach($html->find("text") as $ht) {
   $ht->innertext .= "<span>end of each text node</span>";
}
$html->save();
echo $html;   // echo modified html
```

Just replace the `<span>` element with your `$var`.

Comment: Actually I didnt need the $html->save(); line.. it 'does' work.. however I have upgraded to your operator (.=) vs my archaic way of doing it before... (so thanks)..

However, it ended up not working as I intended.. is there a way to find the END of the text node/element.. (not just append to the text inside that text element...but find the END and append some text (or even a new div/p element?)

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused what this `END` means. Edit the question with an example of your input `$string` and the desired output to see the idea. Also notice that empty spaces between tags are _ALSO_ text nodes (thats because my tags have no spaces in between.

Comment: I'm at work currently.. but the END means (just that).. the END of the text node/element.. (not inside..but OUTSIDE of the 'tag')..

Currently if I do what is shown above..  it can (for example) take the TEXT of a LINK.. and append the INSERT var ($var or $string) to the text of that LINK.. hence breaking it.. or making it look 'odd'

Example:

Comment: Example:

Original-
My Link

After-
My LinkINSERT TRANSLATION HERE >>

Becomes the LINK..

I guess I'm more or less looking for a way to append this text or even a new element AFTER the tag/node/element that has the (plain) text in it closes.

Comment: My Overall goal was to grab ALL text/paragraphs from a site/page..
So it can be passed off to be translated.

So after each CHUNK of plain text.. I want to add (on a new line, new element) the text: INSERT TRANSLATION HERE >>

(I dont care if it wrapped in a p tag or a div tag..etc.. or just plain text inserted AFTER the text element is closed.  (as to NOT actually alter the text that is scrapped in anyway..

But to have a placeholder for where the translation should go.

Hope that make more sense now.